# Variance of subset vs total variance

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

Is it true that the variance of subset is smaller than variance of the total set? Given each element in the set is a N-dimensional vector, and the distance is defined as Euclidean distance. Variance is defined as in statistics term (sum of square of Euclidean distance to the mean data point).

One thing for sure is that if the total variance is 0, then the variance of subset should be 0 as well.

Comment: Variance is actually the mean square rather than the sum of squares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the question is about sample variance. Here is a one-dimensional example.

We have two samples, $1,0,0,0$ and the subsample $1,0$.

The first sample variance is 
$$\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{9}{16}+\frac{1}{16}+\frac{1}{16}+\frac{1}{16}\right).$$ This is $\frac{3}{16}$.

The variance of the subsample is $\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}\right)$, which is $\frac{1}{4}$. This is greater than $\frac{3}{16}$.

Added: More generally, let our full sample of $n$ be $1,-1,0,0,\dots,0$, and let the subsample be $1,-1$. Then the subsample has variance $1$. while the full sample has variance $\frac{2}{n}$.